# selectbox without submit button

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I want to POST my values from selectbox without submit button. And want to get values as automatically drop down menu selects value

Trying below sample code but isnt getting required output

```
<form action="cal1.php" method="post">
  <select name="modelS" onChange="submit();">
    <option value="all" selected>Show All</option>
    <option value="3 Dr">3 Dr</option>
    <option value="5 Dr">5 Dr</option>
    <option value="Cabriolet">Cabriolet</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="confirm bike" name="alldetails">
</form>
```

Now, able to get post values with below code:
But just 1 more query that incase if i remove submit line (remove submit button) and need to get POST value how can i retieve them (ie. without submit button). I tried by using hide but not able to resolve.

```
 <?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ echo $_POST['modelS'];}?>

<form action="cal1.php" method="post"> 
<select name="modelS" onchange="this.form.elements['submit'].click();">
     <option value="A" selected>Show All</option>
     <option value="B">B</option>
     <option value="C">C</option>
     <option value="D">D</option>
</select>
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" name=post VALUE=$_POST['modelS']>
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="search" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: select onchange="sendForm()"

Comment: You just need `onChange="this.form.submit();"`

Comment: you will need to look at adding ajax calls to "get values automatically as drop down menu selects value".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you rely on the submit button value you need to emulate clicking it:

```
<select name="modelS" onchange="this.form.elements['alldetails'].click();">
```

Just submitting the form won't put a value in `$_POST['alldetails']`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="modelS" onChange="submit(this);">
<script language="text/javascript">
    function submit(formField) {
        jQuery(formField).closest('form').submit();         
    }
</script>
```