# How to fetch a value from a listbox after selection using javascript without a submitting

Tags: php, javascript, drop-down-menu, yii, listbox

I program in php (Yii framework) and I would like to fetch values from several (single-selection) listboxes right after each of them is selected. I want to fetch them without going to another page or reloading the current page. Eventually, these values should end up in $_SESSION.

The closest thread I found here (
[selectbox without submit button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14939640/selectbox-without-submit-button)
)
does not address my problem. It still relies on a button and it's unclear how to deal with the fetched values in php.

I assume that I need a function like dropDownList() (
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#dropDownList-detail
) which has an "option" field that allows for javascript code.

The functions I found so far - activeDropDownList() and dropDownList() - do not have an "option field". (Or at least it isn't documented.)

What function (or combination of functions) would you suggest to use?

Answer (score 0):

Just hook up an onchance event listener to the select-boxes in question. Inside that event listener, just get their value and to a .ajax() call using jquery to send the value to a server-side php script, where you can do whatever you need with it.

See:
http://api.jquery.com/change/
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/